# random keeps returning the intital, randomized output

Tags: python, discord.py

'''this is my code that contains a discord.py commands. everytime this command is ran it returnts the same randomized number, is there any way to randomize it again after the command is ran?''''

```
successmsg = "rob success(placehold)"
msg1 = "your robbing failed(placeholder)"
decision = random.randint(1, 100)
@bot.command()
async def rob(ctx, user: discord.User):
    if decision >= 50:
        await ctx.send(successmsg + str(decision))
    elif decision < 50:
        await ctx.send(msg1 + str(decision))
```

'''this is my code that contains a discord.py commands. everytime this command is ran it returnts the same randomized number, is there any way to randomize it again after the command is ran?''''

Comment: Simply put the assignment to `decision` inside the function, so it gets re-rolled every time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Your `decision` variable is only assigned *once*. You want to assign it each time the function is run.

```
successmsg = "rob success(placehold)"
msg1 = "your robbing failed(placeholder)"
@bot.command()
async def rob(ctx, user: discord.User):
    decision = random.randint(1, 100)
    if decision >= 50:
        await ctx.send(successmsg + str(decision))
    elif decision < 50:
        await ctx.send(msg1 + str(decision))
```

Note that your `elif decision < 50:` could just as easily be `else:`.